# Remove quotes from vector element in order to use it as a value

Tags: r

Suppose that I have a vector `x` whose elements I want to use to extract columns from a matrix or data frame `M`.

If `x[1] = "A"`, I cannot use `M$x[1]` to extract the column with header name `A`, because `M$A` is recognized while `M$"A"` is not. How can I remove the quotes so that `M$x[1]` is `M$A` rather than `M$"A"` in this instance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use `$` in this case; use `[` instead. Here's a minimal example (if I understand what you're trying to do).

```
mydf <- data.frame(A = 1:2, B = 3:4)
mydf
#   A B
# 1 1 3
# 2 2 4

x <- c("A", "B")
x
# [1] "A" "B"

mydf[, x[1]]                  ## As a vector
# [1] 1 2

mydf[, x[1], drop = FALSE]    ## As a single column `data.frame`
#   A
# 1 1
# 2 2
```

I think you would find your answer in the [R Inferno](http://www.burns-stat.com/pages/Tutor/R_inferno.pdf). Start around Circle 8: "Believing it does as intended", one of the "string not the name" sub-sections.... You might also find some explanation in the line *`The main difference is that $ does not allow computed indices, whereas [[ does.`* from the help page at `?Extract`.

---

Note that this approach is taken because the question specified using the approach to *extract columns from a matrix or data frame*, in which case, the `[row, column]` mode of extraction is really the way to go anyway (and the `$` approach would not work with a `matrix`).

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I need. Could you please explain why I cannot do the same using $, since I thought this was equivalent to [[]]