# Difference between $ and [] in data.frame inside functions

Tags: r

Let's introduce two functions:

```
test_f <- function(df, var) {
  print(df$var)
}

test_s <- function(df, var) {
  print(df[, var])
}
```

And the `df` itself:

```
df <- data.frame(c(0:10))
colnames(df) <- "X"
```

What I'm missing when running, the `$` version returns `NULL`, but `[]` prints the result correctly:

```
> test_f(df, "X")
NULL
> test_s(df, "X")
 [1]  0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19548816/remove-quotes-from-vector-element-in-order-to-use-it-as-a-value/19548885#19548885

Comment: See also [**this answer**](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18228613/1478381) for more info on `$` subsetting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using the `[` approach has its advantages, among which are being able to easily specify both the rows and columns you want (note the use of plural there) and being able to use the same syntax for a `data.frame` or a `matrix`.

If you wanted to make your function work, you would have to use `eval(parse(...))` to help R figure out what exactly you want to extract.

Here's an example:

```
test_f <- function(df, var) {
  a <- deparse(substitute(df))
  b <- deparse(substitute(var))
  Get <- paste(a, b, sep = "$")
  eval(parse(text = Get))
}
test_f(df, X)
#  [1]  0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
```

Comment: Great answer. The example could be simplified using `Get <- paste("df", var, sep="$")`